# Equation for water rower

Tags: experimental-physics

I have this water rower ([Sunny Health & Fitness Water Rowing Machine w/LCD Monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075MB7DM8)) :

[image]

I am going to make a monitor for it (to calculate time/500m and watts). I am going to attach a magnet to the tip of one of the blades and a sensor on the inside of the tank. I was wondering what the physic equations to calculate the minutes/500m were. Please ask any clarifying questions.

**Further information :**

The monitor provided with the machine is very inaccurate and cheap.

The handle is attached to a fabric cord. The cord goes into the machine and goes around a pulley (it is now parallel with the cord coming from the handle). It then goes around a circle and is wrapped around many times. When the handle is pulled, the circle moves, which it attached to a shaft.

Also attached to that pole/shaft is the fan. The fan has three blades at the end of three poles. The blades are a couple inches wide and are about 1/4 in water. There is also a bungie cord wrapped around the pole to bring the handle back. I don't think that the bungie cord changes the equation.

Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note : there are several images of better quality on the Amazon website linked in the 1st paragraph.

Comment: This is so broad at the moment... design of the rower, type of pump, displacement, type of drive...

Comment: You could compare it against a rowing software. Leo Lazauskas was an adviser of sorts to the Australian rowing team, and produced a model of actual rowing performance that he made available to the public. It is really just a workbench program, and takes a lot of figuring out. But you could select a hull and some standard conditions, and then compare your stroke rate, power, and stroke geometry to the model's. [Free Internet Rowing Model](https://www.boatdesign.net/threads/free-internet-rowing-model-2-32-released.52866/). Leo is retired now and no longer supports his proggies.

Comment: @Solarmike I am not sure what details to give. Please ask for any detail/photos and I will provide them.

Comment: @ScottGibbard If we assume the rowing machine is designed to imitate the actual resistance when rowing (which I suspect it is). I believe the problem is made far easier by putting the magnet on the chain of connected to the handle. This would allow you to measure stroke rate and with stroke length (which you will have to measure once manually or come up with a system to measure it on the go) could be used to determine minutes/500m.

Comment: @spaghettification I do like that idea, I will definitely experiment with it.